# Set Limit and clear in nsmutableString

Tags: iphone, nsmutablestring

I need to limit the number of characters that can be appended to an nsmutablestring to 10. 
Also i need to clear its contents on a button press.
What is the best method to do that?
pls help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a category.  Something like this:

```
@interface NSMutableString (append10)
-(void)appendString:(NSString *)aString;
@end

@implementation NSMutableString (append10)

-(void)appendString:(NSString *)aString
{
    NSString *toAppend = aString;
    if ([aString length] > 10)
    {
        // truncate string
    }

    [super appendString:toAppend];
}

@end
```

Comment: or you could have whatever method that builds the string check the length :)